# Laravel - How to use jQuery AJAX ( $.ajax({}) ) in Laravel to perform specific action?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

In one of my **Laravel Application**, I have a list of users along with **approve and reject** button (with each user record).

Now What I want to do is: performing those **approve** and **reject** action through **jQuery** rather than form submitting. But I can't figure out how to use **jQuery AJAX** along with all required data to the desired URL and receive a response from that URL to perform further action.

So my question is: How can I use jQuery AJAX in Laravel Application to send data from the front-end and catch those record from the backend (I hope Requests $request can catch those info) and also receive a response from the backend to process further action in the front-end?

TIA

I commonly use the following way in CodeIgnitor, but I can't figure out how to use a similar way in Laravel:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url goes here',
    data: {
        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':   csrf_token,
        'id'        :   $.trim( $('#target_id').val() ),
        'status'    :   $.trim( $('#extra_column').val() )
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (r) {
        //action of success
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

an example for ajax request in laravel

in ajax request gvie URL like

```
url = "{{ route('product.productmediadelete')}}";
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::any("product/productMediaDelete", [
        'as'   => 'product.productmediadelete',
        'uses' => 'ProductController@productMediaDelete',
    ]);
```

ProductController.php

```
public function productMediaDelete(Request $request)
{
    //do the action
}
```